# Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-ChildItem'

Tags: powershell, syntax-error

I am not a scripter at all.  Someone else had created this script for me and it has previously worked.  The only thing that has changed is the drive letter (which I did change in the script - it is currently drive E).  But it is not working now.  All it is supposed to do is pull back a list of files in a specified folder and save it as a text file in that directory; in this case, it's my karaoke song collection.

When I run the script now, I get:

> `Get-Process` : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument `Get-ChildItem`.

Here is the original script:

```
PS C:\Users\Tina> Get-ChildItem "F:\My Music\Karaoke\*.*" | Set-Content "F:\My Music\Karaoke\test.txt"
```

I'd like to make it so that it just pulls back all .mp3's, if that's possible, too.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't see Get-Process used in the script you provided, is it the complete script?

Comment: Don't paste this part: PS C:\Users\Tina>

Comment: @Micky PS is an alias for Get-Process.

Comment: @Swonkie completely overlooked that and assumed he was pasting from shell into question. Good catch

Comment: @Swonkie ohhhh, that must be the best gotcha of the year. I thought he pasted the prompt along with the code. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be copying and pasting this to the command line I will assume there was a typo that caused this issue. After a couple of quick tests to try and guess what the accident was I was unable to replicate exactly. Not being a scripter might make this harder but I recommend saving this code to a ps1 file so that you can just double click on it.

```
Get-ChildItem "F:\My Music\Karaoke\*.mp3" | Set-Content "F:\My Music\Karaoke\test.txt"
```

**Warning**

In order for the this file to work for you you have to allow PowerShell to execute it. If you run the shell as administrator once and run this code

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned
```

It will allow your script to run. Keep in mind this is a site for scripters to get help. You should expect answers like this.

Comment: Not sure why the original code flaked (even when I changed the drive letter), but this works when I change the drive letter!  Thanks!  I save the command as a text file, changed the extension to .ps1 then when I want to run it, I right-click and "Run with PowerShell".  Thank you! (Not a problem about the answer...I can usually follow but am not familiar enough with the syntax or commands to know.)